# How to convert CString to const char*?

Tags: mfc, double, cstring

i want to convert CString to const char*, i used that `const char* cstr = (LPCTSTR)CString;` but it doesn't compile,so how to do that, or how to convert CString to double, i used this method _tstof but it returns 0 when i passed a CString to it, so i want to convert CString to const char* inorder to pass the converted value to the method atof(), here's an example:

```
int nTokenPos=0;
CString leftDigit,rightDigit;
double firstNum,secondNum;

if(dialog->myValue.Find('X')!=-1){
CString resToken = dialog->myValue.Tokenize(_T("X"), nTokenPos);
leftDigit=resToken;
OutputDebugString(leftDigit);
while(!resToken.IsEmpty())
{
   resToken = dialog->myValue.Tokenize(_T("X"), nTokenPos);
   rightDigit=resToken;
   rightDigit+="\n";
  //OutputDebugString(rightDigit);
}
 firstNum= _tstof(leftDigit);
 secondNum=_tstof(rightDigit);
 OutputDebugString(leftDigit);
 OutputDebugString(rightDigit);
 TRACE( "First_Number %d\n",firstNum); --->OutPuts ZERO
 TRACE( "\nSecond_Number %d\n",secondNum); --->OutPuts ZERO
//MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(firstNum,secondNum);
 TRACE( "The result %d\n",MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(firstNum,secondNum));
```

Comment: Could you show an example how you pass it in and get the result `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
const char* cstr = (LPCTSTR)CString;
```

doesn't compile because I guess you are building an UNICODE build of your project and therefore _T expands to a 2-byte character (a wide character).

To make this conversion working you could use the ATL macros. Like:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
const char* cstr = T2A((LPCTSTR)CString);
```

However, this is not really related to your initial problem as you are using anyways _tstof() which handles the _T issues for you.

**[Edited]:**

The mistake is somewhere else. The format string of the TRACE is not using the wright placeholder for a float/double. Instead of %d use %f:

```
CString leftDigit = _T("12.5");
double  firstNum = _tstof(leftDigit);
TRACE(_T("%f\n"), firstNum);
```

I tried this and got 12.50000000 printed in the Output pane of VS.

Comment: by using 'firstNum= _tstof((LPCTSTR)leftDigit);' it still doesn;t work!!

Comment: One note about T2A().  I think it just truncates the 2-byte chars into single-byte chars.  I don't think it does a proper conversion from a two-byte representation to a single-byte representation.  If you're building UNICODE but all your strings are really just ANSI then thats not an issue.  But if you really do get Unicode chars in there which aren't within the ANSI range, you would want to use an API which would do a proper conversion to UTF-8.  [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) is a Windows API which would do that for you.

Comment: @Nerdtron No, those ATL macros also use ::WideCharToMultiByte. However, they always assume an ASCII string (CP_ACP) and convert them to UTF-16. So if you want/have to deal with other conversions you can't take them.

Comment: ok, so the same thing applies then -- they're going to truncate anything which actually is using the 2 bytes and so you'd need to do a proper conversion (using different args in a call yourself to WideCharToMultiByte) if you wanted to be able to handle those cases.

Comment: Yes, a conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 won't work for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using UNICODE or not. You should use generic text mapping.
Anyway:

```
CString csTest(_T("Test"));

const TCHAR* cstr = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)csTest;
```

Comment: Why do you assign a non-const string to a pointer to a const string? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CString s( _T( "ala bala portocala" ) );
 CStringA s2( s );
 const char* c = s2;
```